# How can I override the static file handler in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Specifically, how can I assign a new handler to the "static" endpoint? I know I can change the `static_folder` and `static_path`, but I specifically want to assign a different function to handle requests of any url that are routed to the "static" endpoint in the routing map. I've tried assigning an empty `werkzeug.routing.Map` to the `<Flask app>.url_map` but to no avail - I still get an error ("`View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: static`") when attempting to `add_url_rule`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Set `static_folder` to `None` to prevent Flask from registering the view:

```
app = Flask(static_folder=None)
```

Now you are free to create your own.

Alternatively, have the `static` view use a different URL path, and give your alternative a different endpoint name:

```
app = Flask(static_url_path='/flask_static')

@route('/static/<path:filename>')
def my_static(filename):
    # ...
```

Flask will always use the endpoint name `static` for the view it creates, so the above uses `my_static` instead.

Comment: Setting the static folder to `None` appears to have done what I needed. Thanks for the speedy turnaround!